# Resize issue in Firefox - on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm having a bit of an issue, I have the script below, and if works fine in Chrome, IE (partially Safari), but not in Firefox.

In IE, Chrome and Safari, it sets the background-position on #main div, but in Firefox, it doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

```
var $navElm = $(".nav-left-large");

if ($navElm.length > 0) {
    var $main = $("#main"),
        $article = $(".container.pl-article"),
        $nav = $navElm[0],
        lastResize;

    $(window).on("load resize", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("start");
            var w = parseInt($article.css("margin-left"), 10),
                w2 = $nav.offsetWidth;

            if (lastResize !== w) {
                $main.css("background-position-x", "-" + (3000 - (w + w2)) + "px");
                lastResize = w;
            }
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background-position-x is not supported by firefox. Is made by ie, and copy by chrome.

Use `background-position: [x-value]px 0` instead

(first, the x value, and then the y.. in your case, 0)

Comment: Ok, duely noted - however, it's not the problem here - The problem is that it never runs the function $("window).on("load, resize") - It's not even printing out what is in the console.log()

Comment: Why use the setTimeout with 0 ms? Toggle the timeout function, use only the pure code inside the "load resize" event